# Free C/C++ geometric math library offering polygons, splines, subdivs..?

Tags: math, graphics, 3d

Free 3D geometric math library recommendations which offering polygon, spline, subdivs..?

I prefer open-source and BSD like license library.

Comment: Sorry for my unclear question. I just realized I was asking for math lib instead of graphics drawing lib.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For polygon meshes (and subd) take a look at [OpenMesh](http://www.openmesh.org).

For polygon manipulation [CGAL](http://www.cgal.org/) is king, but be aware of it's restrictive licensing.

Comment: CGAL is really cool, but not very intuitive to use, I think. The 1100+ pages manual helps but also intimidates me.

Answer (score 1):

What do you think about this: [Cairo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cairo_%28graphics%29) or [Qt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt_%28framework%29)?

It would be helpful, if you gave some context.

Comment: Thank you and sorry for my unclear question. I just realized I was asking for math lib instead of graphics drawing lib. Sorry again. However +1 for letting me know the Cairo! It looks good!

Comment: If you are still looking for a library, I recommend you take a look at: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_numerical_libraries

Comment: I'm reading the page. However you gave me a search hint! Thanks!